# How to insert image in Yagmail? (Python)

Tags: python, image, email, smtp, yagmail

I have a Yagmail script where I want to send an email formated like so:

*Hello! Below is a picture.*

*img.png*

*Goodbye!*

However, my script is just sending the image all the way at the bottom of the email. Here is my code:

```
img = "img.PNG"
body = "Hello! Below is a picture." + img + "Goodbye!"

contents = [body, img]
yag.send("receiver@gmail.com", "Subject", contents)
```

How would you send an email using a format where you can position the image between blocks of text? Help is appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

```py
contents = [yagmail.inline("/path/to/local/image")]
```